# Radar chart using Plotly and Flask

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, flask, plotly

I am trying to display a radar chart using Plotly on my Flask App but unfortunately, I do not succeed, the image is not displayed.

Here is the code I am using :

backend.py

```
create_figure():
 list_1 = [var1, var2, var3, var4, var5 ]
 list_2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    r=list_1,
    theta= list_2))
 fig = px.line_polar(df, r='r', theta='theta', line_close=True)
 fig.show()
```

app.py

```
@app.route('/fig/')
def fig():
  fig = create_figure()
  img = StringIO()
  fig.savefig(img)
  img.seek(0)
  return send_file(img, mimetype='image/png')
```

Here's the HTML code:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('fig') }}" alt="Image" height="100">
```

Could someone please enlighten me? Thank you!

Comment: Don't you get error ? Maybe first save normally in file to see what you get. And maybe don't use `show()` when you save in file. And you need `return fig` in `def create_figure()` to do `fig = create_figure()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I do not get any errors, the app works perfectly but the image is not displayed. I have made the changes that you talked about, it still not working...

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you ahve in values. You can also save in file on disk to see what you get. Maybe you have to set `png` in `savefig()` to create `png` data instread of `jpg`